# Convert vector of seconds to dates (reverse ISOdatetime)

Tags: r

I did this to make some operations with the seconds:

```
x <- as.numeric(unclass(ISOdatetime(year=2017,
                                month=2,
                                day=9,
                                hour=8,
                                min=38,
                                sec=39,
                                tz="Greenwich")))

x
[1] 1486629519
```

Now, I want to reverse it. That is, obtain from the `1486629519` the year, month, day, hour, minutes, and seconds as separate objects.

Of course I'm not dealing with just one quantity but with a large vector of seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.POSIXct`:

```
R> .POSIXct(1486629519, tz="GMT")
[1] "2017-02-09 08:38:39 GMT"
```

If you want to easily be able to extract the components, you can convert to `POSIXlt`:

```
R> p <- as.POSIXlt(.POSIXct(1486629519, tz="GMT"))
R> p$year + 1900  # years since 1900
[1] 2017
R> p$mon + 1      # months are zero-based
[1] 2
R> p$mday         # mday is day of month; day of year is also available
[1] 9
R> p$hour
[1] 8
R> p$min
[1] 38
R> p$sec
[1] 39
```